# Maximum space required for ubuntu repository

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, localrepository

I am using **Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal)** version and it is at EOL.

The repositories for older releases that are not supported get moved to an archive server.
These repositories are available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.

Now I have to set up this repository on my local server so that we can fetch  packages from it instead of archive server. For setting repository we can use [Apt-Mirror](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/create-local-ubuntu-repository-using-apt-mirror-and-apt-cacher).

I also refer different documentation like

http://www.unixmen.com/setup-local-repository-ubuntu-14-0413-1013-04-server/

http://www.tecmint.com/setup-local-repositories-in-ubuntu/

But **none of them specifically mentioned required maximum space.**

So I have a question how much maximum space required for setting ubuntu repository.

My `sources.list` file is as follows

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 2):

From your 1st link:

> Be mindful that, you need at least 50GB or more free space in your local or external hard drive.

From your 2nd link:

> For a complete mirror cache your server needs at least 120G free space reserved for local repositories.

So you can expect at least 120Gb for a complete mirror.

But... even without a number I would just get a 1Tb disk or even 2Tb. Those are cheap even if needed in a server.

Comment: currently I have 60 Gb space on the server if I go for creating mirror is it allow me?

Comment: For a full mirror you needs twice that (at least).

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen, https://www.debian.org/mirror/size ?

It totals 2415GB

Also, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors ?

It totals 912GB

Answer (score 1):

Skip the source packages. And backports, if you don't need them. For 14.04, mirroring the amd64 and i386 architectures and skipping source packages and backports, my mirror needs ~100G.

Comment: you mean if I skip all the source packages that doesn't affect, right?

Comment: @user2622247 If you have never use the command `apt-get source`, feel free to go ahead and skip them.